# Shred multiple JSON arrays using JSON_TABLE in Terdata

Tags: json, teradata, teradatasql

I have to shred a JSON using Teradata JSON functions.
Suppose I hava JSON like

```
{
    "products":[{"category":"car","name":"toyota"},
              {"category":"aircraft","name":"boeing"},
              {"category":"fruit","name":"pear"}],
    "price": [{"name" : "toyota", "value": 560000},
            {"name" : "boeing", "value": 53690000},
            {"name" : "pear", "value": 387}]
}
```

I tried to use the below query to shred the JSON.

```
SELECT * FROM JSON_Table 
( ON  (SELECT id, json_data FROM MyDB.TestJSONTable)
    USING rowexpr('$.products[*]')
        colexpr('[{ "jsonpath" : "$.category", "type" : "VARCHAR(100)" },
                { "jsonpath" : "$.name", "type" : "VARCHAR(100)" }
        ]')
) AS JT(ID, category, name )
```

This will give me the result as

| ID | category | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | toyota |
| 1 | aircraft | boeing |
| 1 | fruit | pear |

Now how can I get the result as below using JSON_TABLE in the same query.

| ID | category | name | prod_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | toyota | toyota | 560000 |
| 1 | aircraft | boeing | boeing | 53690000 |
| 1 | fruit | pear | pear | 387 |

I know I could create a new query and join back with the first result to get the output. But I wanted to know if there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: If you don't split your arrays out into separate derived tables, how would you ever "join" them back together?  Assuming that the first row in each array goes together, etc, seems pretty risky.